# Creating a Second Set of Commands for (Sub-)Subsections and Paragraphs, Numbered but no Headings

Tags: sectioning, memoir

I am working on a long posthumous contribution to an edited volume which I have had to convert from Word to tex, and am now faced with the challenge of the author having used a peculiar way of structuring his paper: He has given numbers to what I would think of in terms of LaTeX as `subsection`s, `subsubsection`s and `paragraph`s, but without giving them a heading. Additionally he occasionally jumps in such a way that, for example, after `subsection` 15.3 the next `subsubsection` is 15.4.1. I wonder what is the best way of dealing with it. The author has used his numbering system extensively for cross references, so changing things would have to be done with extreme care. I am now considering creating a set of new commands replicating the author's desired structure. I am not going to modify the style for the whole volume, as only his contribution has this peculiar structure.

I have now managed to change the respective after-skips, but would prefer to have them as separate commands, that step up the respective counters, make the entries to the toc, (well, probably not necessary) and use the formatting of my example, but *don't* touch the formatting of the regular `\subsection`, `\subsubsection` and `\paragraph`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}


\makeatletter
\setsecheadstyle{\bfseries}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\bfseries\raggedright}
\setaftersubsecskip{-1em}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{}
\setaftersubsubsecskip{-1em}
\setbeforeparaskip{-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}
\setparaheadstyle{}
\setafterparaskip{-1em}
\makeatother



\setsecnumformat{\csname ts#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\tssection}{\thesection\qquad\quad}
\newcommand{\tssubsection}{\thesubsection\qquad}
\newcommand{\tssubsubsection}{\thesubsubsection\qquad}
\newcommand{\tsparagraph}{\theparagraph\enspace}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}

\setsecnumdepth{paragraph}

\begin{document}
\section{Heading} Text
\subsection{Heading} Text
\subsubsection{Heading} Text
\paragraph{Heading} Text
\section{} Text
\subsection{} Text
\subsubsection{} Text
\paragraph{} Text
\end{document}
```

The first set just being for testing purposes. The second set looks as follows:
[image: sample]

I assume that the manual stepping up of counters would be trivially done by
`\setcounter{subsection}{4}` just before something like `\mysubsubsection{}` where I'd expect a "15.4.1".

Or, I wonder, would an altogether different approach be advised for this?

Edit: I am getting the impression that it will be easier to at the beginning of the concerned contribution do

```
\setaftersubsecskip{-1em}
\setaftersubsubsecskip{-1em}
\setafterparaskip{-1em}
```

and at the end revert them back to their original values, i.e.

```
\setaftersubsecskip{1sp}
\setaftersubsubsecskip{1sp}
\setafterparaskip{1sp}
```

Comment: Just issue a `\begingroup` in front of that contribution and a `\endgroup` afterwards to undo all the changes you do inside of that contribution (as long as they are not globally made).

Comment: I wouldn't use `\thesection\qquad` or stuff like that. That results in space dependent on the width of the number in question. Instead I'd use `\makebox[15mm][l]{\thesection}`.

Comment: I sympathise. From what you say the author has not used a logical numbering system unlike with LaTeX. Might it be better for this particular contribution to do all the numbering yourself by hand? It might require a new set of counters and labels.